# Что происходит с указателем после выполнения функции с malloc?

Tags: c, память

Вот у меня есть пример вот такой файл:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>

void fkfkfkfkfk() {
 void* a = malloc(sizeof(char));
}

int main() {
 fkfkfkfkfk();
 return 0;
}
```

Этот файл полноценно работает, я хотел бы спросить что происходит после выполнения функции с указателем (с занятым памятью), она остаётся навсегда занятой, или автоматически после выполнения функции указатель стирается

Answer (score 2, accepted):

После выполнения функции память остается выделенной; после завершения программы - освобождается.

Так как после выхода из функции указатель на выделенную память потерян, в данном конкретном случае вы получаете утечку памяти.

Comment: Это печально :(

Comment: А нет ли способо авто очистки

Comment: В С нет; в С++ можно воспользоваться т.н. интеллектуальным указателем.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо

Comment: @Redis, и все же некотрые люди [делали](https://hboehm.info/gc/index.html) и [продолжают делать](https://maplant.com/gc.html) GC библиотеки для C/C++

Comment: @avp Просто интересно - а как вы сами относитесь к этим решениям, которые - с моей точки зрения, конечно - в детерминированность и строгость C/C++ вносят как минимум элемент случайности...? Не говоря о других неприятностях.

Comment: @Harry, в тех программах, что я пишу, применять не собираюсь. Вообще, они без сомнения интресны, но совершенно *не в духе* сишного подхода. Может быть даже, если посмотреть поглубже, вредны, расширяют  дорогу бездумной траты ресурсов. Поэтому не удивлюсь, даже если возникнут диалекты языков (т.е. поддержка со стороны компилятора) с их использованием.

Comment: А интересно, массивы стираются, или тоже утечки памяти происходит

Comment: Если вы о локальных массивах - то тут никакой утечки памяти нет, они освобождаются при выходе из функции (и потому нельзя возвращать указатели на них из функций).

Comment: @Harry фуух, я уже испугался, всё каждый указатель буду free

Comment: Иногда это как раз не нужно - например, вы выделяете память в одной функции, передаете в другую, третью, а уж потом удаляете. Просто все надо делать вовремя :)